# Constructing a select element using a foreign key relationship

Tags: cakephp

Here's my simple database schema and models:

```
create table personas --done
(
    id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre varchar(128),
    apellido varchar(128),
    fecha_de_nacimiento date,
    sexo Bool,
    carnet_de_identidad varchar(64),
    direccion_domicilio varchar(128),
    direccion_oficina varchar(128),
    ciudad varchar(128),
    estado varchar(128),
    pais varchar(128),
    email_principal varchar(512),
    email_secundario varchar(512),
    telefono varchar(64),
    movil varchar(64),
    titulo_profesional varchar(128),
    universidad varchar(128),
    foto_archivada blob,
    curriculum text,
    comentarios text
);

create table coordinadors
(
    id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    persona_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (persona_id) REFERENCES personas(id)
);

# My CakePHP models:

class Persona extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array('Tutor'); // Some other relationship ommitted for brevity.
}

class Tutor extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Persona';
}
```

I'm trying to create an HTML `<select>` element with only `persona` objects that are `coordinadors`. In plain English, that would be: `Show me a collection of all the persona choices who are coordinadors.`

Here's what I have so far:

```
$coordinadores = $this->Coordinador->find('all');

Output:
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'Coordinador' => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'persona_id' => '2'
    ),
    'Persona' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'nombre' => 'Sergioa',
        'apellido' => 'Tapia',
        'fecha_de_nacimiento' => '2012-10-01',
        'sexo' => false,
        'carnet_de_identidad' => '215154',
        'direccion_domicilio' => 'qwerqwerqwer3',
        'direccion_oficina' => 'qwerqwerwqerqwer',
        'ciudad' => 'Sqwerqwerwqerra',
        'estado' => 'Sqwerqwerqwerquz',
        'pais' => 'qwerqwerqwerqwer',
        'email_principal' => 'serqwerqwerqwerm',
        'email_secundario' => 'stqwerwqerqwercom',
        'telefono' => 'qwerqwerqwer',
        'movil' => 'qwerqwerqwer',
        'titulo_profesional' => 'Ing qwerqwerqwer',
        'universidad' => 'qwerqwerqwer',
        'foto_archivada' => null,
        'curriculum' => '<p>oiasdfoiwecwec</p>',
        'comentarios' => '<p>jojqwefijwecwc wecwec</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>wcwecwec</p>'
    )
    )
    )
```

How can I use the Persona obeject to create a simple `<select>` element?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've already done the hard work. Now you just have to to output your result:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach ($coordinadores as $coordinador) {
    echo '<option value="' . $coordinador['Persona']['id'] . '">';
    echo $coordinador['Persona']['apellido'] . ' ' . $coordinador['Persona']['nombre'];
    echo '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: This is a solution I came up with. So you're saying there's not CakePHP 'magic' way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: That is not how you use cakephp.

Comment: @dogmatic69: If you can show me a better way I'm all ears. :)

Comment: Use `Model::find('list')` in controller and `FormHelper::select()` in view.